# How to make accordian display after ajax call is completed

Tags: jquery

On click of the Accordian i am doing a ajax call and appending data to the accordian contents

The accoridian is working fine without the ajax call , please see the jsfiddle here (withOut ajax call)

http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/1145/

But when i integrated ajax with accordian , the accordian is not opening

http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/1144/

This is my code

```
$(function() {
  $('#accordion .content').hide();
  $('#accordion h2').click(function() {
    var clcikedid = $(this).attr('id');
    var ajaxcall = $.ajax({
      url: 'test',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('ajx call completed');
      }
    });
    ajaxcall.done(function() {
      if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Could you please tell me how to resolve the issue ??

Comment: You have problem with the scope. Check inside ajaxcall.done function is `this` that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not to use `this` in done function:

```
if ($('#' + clcikedid).next().is(':hidden')) {
    $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
    $('#' + clcikedid).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
}
```

You have saved id in `clcikedid`. I use it to solve the issue. The value of `this` is not what you aspect. It is the ajax call object.